# Wordpress admin breaks when activating purchased theme

Tags: php, wordpress, themes, http-status-code-404

I have installed a theme 'aaika' to my Wordpress site (fresh installation). After activating that theme, I cant even access the WP dashboard. (it is working fine in my local server - XAMPP)

here is the url http://dezmern.com/
http://dezmern.com/wp-admin/

but when I click on a post, it shows no error http://dezmern.com/2018/10/24/hello-world/

But I can't make any changes to the site through wp-admin. I even changed the active theme name to the default through the DB, still it is not restoring the dashboard. Please help me to sort out this issue.

PS: this theme is running well in another website hosted in a different server.

Thanks

Comment: change define " ('WP_DEBUG', false); " to  " define('WP_DEBUG', true); " in wp-config.php , so that we can identify the error

Comment: the wp_debug value is true only.

Comment: whats the value of 'siteurl' and 'home' fields in wp_options table ?

Comment: both fields are correct " http:// dezmern.com" (I put a space after // to make it completely visible(for you) otherwise it will show just dezmern.com)

Answer (score 0):

In wp-config.php before `require_once` add below code into file :

```
define('CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false); 
define( 'SCRIPT_DEBUG', true );
```

Comment: added the above code. Now it is like:
    define('WP_DEBUG', true);

/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */

/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
 define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');

/** Sets up WordPress vars and included files. */

define('CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false); 
define( 'SCRIPT_DEBUG', true );

require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');

Comment: can you post your htaccess script?

Comment: Yes! here it is :


`# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress`

Comment: but... why my site is not working after theme installation?